# Export Nessus Professional vulnerability scan results listed by vulnerabilities

Tags: nessus

When I export Nessus Professional vulnerability scan results into HTML, the results are listed by host. Is it possible to export Nessus Professional vulnerability scan results listed by vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your report there an option to group by plugins.